# Setup git on an Internal Server [Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I've been following this [Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) to config git on a Ubuntu machine (`MyUbuntu`).
I created a Git account and my `authorized_key` is in `/Home/git/.ssh`

> ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAnXr1ZbTR/l0xlF7dbwiVUH2rf47ht2cHBCAoYigW1iSRk3DUDIp0xZDyaMfJTi3USYXrh3wODjI+U+D3eE9YXCXBDWn7k1tQFQp7QrEpgJgWhWerbLML7IV/JNEBb2k+5dIh5KyEl13r0Umf2ZPWRhUY/tN4vT1lfjy62KKDemYNqr2zxEm/neMvL4jIY4f2uEndGuO7hgsTvXqyjvbqWHDOY3Eeprevo+4iPG8p+g+JTkNQRlcHaL61a8FOwbDbA0xrNWgiHSIQaBDH+tK3xzqLwRjhcQPnwu/0AZ2u7/1EQ+ntaGWJX+zgRR3+kFzadL8wkgBRtCHUrmximHRTvw==
>   windows.user@email.com

The key is generated from a windows pc (`MyWindows`), and the two machines are connected in a local network (can ping each other).

I've created a git repo in /opt/git/project.git in `myubuntu`.
I tried to create a branch on `mywindows` and push to `myubuntu`

> git remote add origin git@myubuntu:/opt/git/project.git
>
> git push origin master

But the error msg it gave me is

> ssh:connect to host myubuntu port 22: Bad file number
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Did I miss any setup steps, what about folder permission of repo on `myubuntu` or missing some ssh setup?

Comment: Are you able to login to your Linux box using putty with that key?  Are the permissions setup so that the git account has read/write access to `/opt/git/project.git`?  Do you see any activity in your `/var/log/auth.log` when you try to do a push?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a connection problem, not a problem with directory permissions. The ssh-service on port 22 of the Ubuntu host is not reachable. Either ssh is not running or port 22 is blocked by a firewall.

On your Ubuntu machine, make sure sshd is running on port 22:

```
sudo netstat -tlnp|grep :22
```

and check that there are no firewall rules in place that block the connection:

```
sudo iptables -nL
```